# Выделение предложения с обеих сторон в файле

Tags: c++

Есть файл. В нём нужно посчитать количество повествовательных предложений и выделить 3 повествовательное предложение с обеих сторон. Повествовательным предложением считать то предложение, которое оканчивается точкой.
Программу я уже написал, и с правой стороны предложение выделяется исправно, но к сожалению с левой стороны не выходит. Приведу пример.

> 1 предложение.
>
> 2 предложение.
>
> 3 предложение?
>
> 4 предложение!
>
> ====> 5 предложение. <====

Примерно так это должно выглядеть, а у меня это так: 5 предложение. <====

При том, хочу отметить, что 2 или более предложения могут идти в одну строчку, то есть не всегда, когда кончается предложение нужно переходить на новую строчку.
Код прилагаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale (0,"rus");
    FILE *f;
    char ch;
    int t=0, kolvo = 0, ob=0;
    if ((f = fopen("File.txt","r"))== NULL)
{
    printf("Невозможно открыть файл.\n");
    return 0;
}
    f = fopen("File.txt","r");  
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf(f, "%c", &ch);
        cout<<ch; 
    }
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        if (ch == '.')
        {       
            kolvo++;
            break;
        }       
    }
     cout<<"\nКоличество повествовательных предложений:"<<kolvo<<endl<<endl;
     system("pause");
     system("cls");
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        ch = fgetc(f);
        if(ch=='.')t++;
        if(t==3 && ch=='.')
        cout<<"   <======";
        cout<<ch; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну а чего вы хотите, если строку "====>" вы в вашей программе даже не выводите?

Comment: У меня были попытки, но они не к чему не привели) Я обдумывал, какие условия поставить, чтобы программа пропускала предложения с ? и ! знаками и выделяло только 3 повествовательное, но к сожалению ничего не вышло. Просто так, я бы сюда не писал.

Comment: @Nejdan, т. е. вы не понимаете, как узнать где **начинается** «повествовательное» предложение?

Comment: @Eanmos, Да, это моя основная проблема. Мне нужно найти начало этого повествовательного предложения, после чего его выделить, но увы, реализовать не получается.

Comment: @Nejdan, думаю, проще всего будет разбить строку на отдельные предложения (`strtok` по `.?!`), а затем просто посмотреть, какие предложения оканчиваются точкой. Потом поочередно выводить предложения, а где нужно ставить стрелочки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s;
list<string> vs;

istream_iterator<string> first(cin), last;
while (first != last) {
    s += *first;
    if(!ispunct(s.back()))
        s += ' ';
    else {
        vs.emplace_back(s);
        s.clear();
    }
    ++first;
}
vs.remove_if([](string t) {return t.back() != '.'; });
// vs содержит ваши предложения
```

только остается вместо cin использовать файловый обьект
А можно просто найти позиции знаков пунктуации и записывть строку, если строка заканчивается пунктуацией '.', начиная от позиции предыдущего знака пунктуации

Comment: Я очень вам благодарен за ответ, но ведь свой код я скинул не просто так. Я не понимаю, как сделать выделение в начале предложения, с помощью тех методов, которые были уже исп. в моём коде. Я бы мог просто взять ваш код и посчитать, что написал всё сам и быть довольным, но мне хочется доработать свою программу. Не посчитайте это за грубость, пожалуйста. Я действительно благодарен вам за помощь. Но это не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: А мне не понятно как  можно из того, что вы написали, сделать правильно работающий код для данной задачи..,

Comment: Вас понял. Ещё раз спасибо за решение)

Comment: вы просто можете  понять логику решения задачи и  написать самому. Для этого просто все напишите заново. А логика такова: читаете слова из файла и  добавляете в отдельную строку, если в конце слова есть знак (ispunct), то записывете в   контейнер всю строку, очищаете строку, чтобы записать следующее предложение.  Делаете это, пока не достигнете конца файла.  Удаляете из контейнера те предложения, которые заканчиваются не  точкой...

Comment: Я вполне понимаю логику, у меня есть идеи, но к сожалению это задание для института. Даже исп. string (Мы ещё не изучали данный тип, хотя я его иногда использовал) сделает только хуже. К тебе будет очень много вопросов, как работает, что делает, зачем и когда. Не сильно хочется, чтобы после ко мне относились предвзято и приходится делать тем, что есть) Но я вам действительно очень благодарен. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Я очень рад за вас, поскольку вы  размышляете правильно и все правильно понимаете и излогаете. И если  у вас есть трудолюбие, вы достигнете многого.   И  для меня всегда  приятно быть полезным для таких людей как вы. Так что и вам спасибо большое за приятное ощущение